# React Native | App Crash because of "react-native-google-signin"

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

**React Native | react-native-google-signin**

After i install react-native-google-sigin with

```
npm i react-native-google-signin
```

It suddenly crash ( force close ) right when the app start, I have already did all the steps that is told on the github documentation yet when i run my App it crash instantly, without giving any error in the log. ( neither android-log nor adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V does )

Here are my codes:

**build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1" // <--- use this version or newer
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' // <--- use this version or newer
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // <--- use this version or newer
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'App'
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':react-native-google-signin', ':app'
project(':react-native-google-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-signin/android')
include ':app'
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
        }
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

    if (enableHermes) {
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <--- this should be the last line
```

Can someone help me with this error? because when i uninstall **react-native-google-signin** with

```
npm uninstall react-native-google-signin
```

it works just fine

Comment: Hello, Have you tried linking the dependency to your project with react-native-link

Comment: did  you solve this?

Comment: Please add your `package.json` info here too. To debug this it will be helpful to know RN version and google-sign-in version.

Comment: The problem for me was the dependency for react >.59 I used 15.0.0 and that fixed the problem.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'

Comment: Do you have `google-services.json` file?

Answer (score 3):

In app/build.gradle set 
`implementation(project(":@react-native-community_google-signin"))`
instead

```
 implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of React Native Google Signin:

- `react-native-google-signin` for React Native <= 0.59
- `@react-native-community/google-signin` for React Native >= 0.60

Since you are using the first one, I suppose your version of React Native is <= 0.59, if not, you must switch to the community version.

---

Apart from the above, your `android/build.gradle` contains a duplicated `classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle`:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2' // <--- use this version or newer
```

Since React Native Google Signin requires the version 3.1.2 or newer, you can safely remove the second one.

Also, based on what is stated in the documentation, your `android/app/build.gradle` misses the following implementation:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you have Hermes enabled it means you have RN 0.60+

Just use the community version:

`"@react-native-community/google-signin": "^3.0.3"`

RN 0.60+ has autolinking so **you don't need these lines**:

```
// settings.gradle
include ':react-native-google-signin', ':app'
project(':react-native-google-signin').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/google-signin/android')


// MainApplication.java
new RNGoogleSigninPackage()
```

I think you should try to use this autolinking for the other libraries too (you might have to use their latest versions)

If still not working you can get more info here

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/docs/android-guide.md

(Pay attention that step 4 should not be done unless manual linking is used and double check steps 1-3)